# IntelliJ IDEA doesn't give hint about package to be imported

Tags: intellij-idea

Coming from Eclipse world, I really miss this important feature where Eclipse suggests if particular package needs to be imported for compilation error

e.g.

> new ArrayList , this simply says Can't resolve symbol
>   'ArrayList' but doesn't suggest which package to import like eclipse
>   does.

Is this bug with IDEA or some setting needs to be done in it ?

[image]

**[Solution]**

The problem turns out be bad UX from IDEA
If user does mouse over, it show error message as per above screen shot

If user puts mouse somewhere else; it suggests package to import sometimes. It's not as friendly as Eclipse though

[image]

Comment: Not sure why somebody has downvoted without any explanation? If they have used the Eclipse then would have understood this obvious issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've posted answer in bottom part of question. IDEA has got confusing & not so user friendly UX which gives hints about package to import.

I find it more useful in Eclipse, hope IDEA team will fix this

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-import.html